# IBM Notes Fix Pack 7 issue

Tags: jquery, dojo, xpages

I am using both jQuery and Bootstrap in my XPages based application. The jQuery functionalities are working properly on Notes v901 with earlier FixPack like FP5, FP6 but not on FixPack7. Is there any known problem with FixPack7?

Comment: What is not working? What errors do you see?

Comment: Whole jQuery functionality stopped working on FP7 with Notes v901. jQuery DataTables, buttons, Expand/Collapse icons, Dashboard(including pie charts) of jQuery are not working.
All jQuery is working fine on Notes v901 with FP5, FP6, web browsers and Notes v853.

Comment: They may have stopped working, but we can't help without any meaningful errors?! What do you see if you look at the console in firebug for example? Is anything written to the domino log? Without knowing the error(s), there's nothing to go on......

Comment: The application is working properly on all browsers so we are not able to find out any console error. Unfortunately, we don't find any error log on both Notes client log as well as server log.
While migrating to Notes v901 I have read few blogs which states that dojo might block jQuery libraries. By any chance, could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge based on the scant information provided, there is no known issue with FP7 compared to FP6.

The key is identifying how the jQuery / Bootstrap functionality is provided and ensuring it is still available.

> All jQuery is working fine on Notes v901 with FP5, FP6, web browsers and Notes v853

First identify/clarify *how* it's contributed. Typically in the case of most modern XPages applications, this will be using XPages Extension Library from OpenNTF. That was not contributed until after 8.5.3, at which time most developers would have used Bootstrap4XPages. However, you've not confirmed it's using an OSGi plugin at all.

Once you've identified *how* it's contributed, identify *where* it's contributed. "Notes v901" implies XPiNC. For this, the relevant code needs to be available to the relevant Notes Client, as a plugin within the individual Notes Clients where the application is being loaded. Version upgrades can disable plugins (this is why a Widget Catalog is the recommended approach), but without having confirmation that it's contributed with a plugin, that may or may not be a cause. Error logs for Notes Client are in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT, as on a server. Firebug Lite component is the best option for troubleshooting XPiNC client-side issues.

"Web browsers" means the relevant code needs to be available on the relevant server. It depends on how the code has been deployed to the server. If it's contributed with a plugin and has been copied manually into the file structure, it's possible it's been removed. If it's in an Update Site, ensure the setup is still correct.

If it's failing for Designer local preview, plugins need to be in the osgi folder. Again, an upgrade can remove those. But errors would be identified *somewhere*.

But all of this is assuming its contributed via a plugin and guessing at what the plugin is.

> I have read few blogs which states that dojo might block jQuery libraries

This doesn't clarify what the issue those blogs identify is, what versions of Dojo / jQuery are affected etc. If it's a version conflict, browsers connecting to FP7 server would not work either. The only issue I'm aware of is conflict of AMD loading, which I believe was caused by changes in how Dojo worked in Dojo 1.5. I'm not aware of any difference between Dojo in FP6 and FP7 that has caused a conflict. Cross-reference blog dates, the symptoms they identify, the versions they reference and release dates to confirm the blog posts you're reading about don't date earlier than FP7 being released. FOr example, if they pre-date FP7, and your application works on FP6, the blog posts are not likely to be relevant.

The key to all of this is to identify *how* it works and *what's different* where it doesn't work. Without that, you're unlikely to get a definitive answer.